# Unhide text files by java

Tags: java

I tried to hide and unhide a text file. I can hide only but when I tried to unhide, I get an error message.

```
        try {
            //Hide file;
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c attrib +h test.txt");
            //wait for process to get over (i.e. for file hiding)
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }

        //Now, let's test whether file has been hidden or not
        boolean fileHidden = fileToBeHidden.isHidden();

        if (fileHidden) {
            System.out.println(fileName + " is hidden ");
        } else {
            System.out.println(fileName + " isn't hidden ");
        }
```

this method hide file correctly but I couldn't unhide it again

Comment: What is the error message? Please use e.printStackTrace() to find the entire stack trace, then paste it into your question as text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for hide and unhide files.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.fileProcess("test.txt", true);
        Test.fileProcess("test.txt", false);
    }

    public static void fileProcess(String fileName, boolean hide) {
        try {

            // you can change your full
            String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + File.separator
                    + "files"
                    + File.separator + fileName;

            File f = new File(filePath);
            if(!f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(fileName + " file is not exist ");
                return;
            }

            Path file = Paths.get(filePath);
            Files.setAttribute(file, "dos:hidden", hide);

            f = new File(filePath);

            boolean fileHidden = f.isHidden();
            if (fileHidden) {
                System.out.println(fileName + " is hidden ");
            } else {
                System.out.println(fileName + " isn't hidden ");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output like this:

```
test.txt is hidden 
test.txt isn't hidden
```

Comment: I tested it and looks fine. Can you share your error.

Comment: [java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: null\files\test.txt]

it's the same error in hide and unhide

Comment: Your fullPath is wrong. try like this. String filePath = "D:\\test.txt";

Comment: I tried it and copy the path from properties of file and I got the same error again

Comment: I think your fullPath is wrong or file not exist the path.Can you share fullPath string  and your error again

Comment: String fullpath = "D:\\test.txt";
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: null\files\test.txt

Comment: Finally I resolved it by removing : String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir")
                    + File.separator
                    + "files"
                    + File.separator + fileName;
and set it as : String filePath = "D://test.txt";